# Realm for web development

Tags: android, iphone, reactjs, react-native, realm

I have been using a Realm for mobile development and now I am trying to build a website using the same database. I was wondering if a realm database can be used for standard web development.

Comment: Depends on what exactly you wish to achieve! But yes, Realm can be used on server-side on both Linux and Windows via NodeJS and the Realm-JS API.

Comment: Can you please point me toward some resources that would help me with this?

Comment: This is actually terribly underdocumented and this is the only thing I know that shows how to *start out* at all https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/examples/NodeInterprocess/winston-realm.js#L5

Comment: I can't give you any specific date but you are welcome to follow https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2339

Answer (score 0):

[This section](https://docs.realm.io/sync/graphql-web-access) of their "Sync" documentation explains how to use GraphQL for

> retrieving Realm data in a web browser [...]. The API supports retrieving data or applying changes via HTTP requests and realtime subscription events via a Websockets connection.

So yes, a realm database can be used in standard web development (including frontend), via GraphQL.